# React Native post to Node.js/Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, native

I am triying to make a post query from my React Native (expo) app to Node.js server (express). And the post is doing nothing. Even, console.log doesnot work. Please, need your help with this
React Native App code:

```
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            timeout: 20000,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                a: 10,
                b: 20
            })
        };
        fetch(url, options)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded')); 

        console.log('3232');
```

And node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
/// create express app
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/g_data/auth', function(req, res){
    console.log('LOGGED')
    res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

React Native console return : "3232"

node.js console return nothing

No "new incoming connection detected from ...", "LOGGED", as expected.

Please help, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Additional info about versions: "react-native": "^0.69.4", "expo": "~46.0.7", "express": "^4.18.1", node.js - 16.16.0

Comment: at the top of React Native code: `const url = 'http://192.168.88.15:7935/g_data/auth';`

Comment: Are you running your app on emulator or over a pysical device?

Comment: Server on Physical device (laptop). And run app from both iOS emulator and on iPhone (expo go)

Comment: By the way, all get responses works as expected on server.

Comment: I forgot to wrote that app listening was added at the end of node.js app: `app.listen(7935);
console.log('listen port 7935');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! the final solution is in wrong Headers. For some reasons, React Native app send Headers:
`'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'`
But node.js server receives:
`'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'`

So, first, I have installed cors to server, `npm i cors -save` and for some reason left Body Parser, and a little bit modernize headers. Here is a final code:
React Native App:

```
let formdata = '["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]';
        ///console.log(formdata);
        const url = 'http://192.168.88.15:7935/g_data/auth';
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            timeout: 20000,
            mode:'cors',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }, 
            body: formdata
        };
        fetch(url, options)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        /// make design
        setLoading(false);
        /// next code
        console.log('next!');
```

The server code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
/// create express app
var app = express();
/// use cors
app.use(cors())
/// use body req parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/g_data/auth', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send({Message: 'Hello World!'})
});

app.listen(7935);
console.log('listen port 7935');
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe u need to install and import body-parser on your node js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // ++

/// create express app
var app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); // ++

app.post('/g_data/auth', function(req, res){
    console.log('LOGGED')
    res.send('Hello World!')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I also tried with bodyParser, result the same. But the Express documentation says that in version 4.16 and higher it is already enabled by default.

Comment: Try you code, result the same - the silence from server

Comment: try ur post API on postman

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! I added a final code, that works fine. But, thanks for you help, with Postman, I had an ability to analyze data. And the solution was in wrong headers.